replace strings that contains one another
I have this problem
df<-data.frame(SS=c("New age, wow 20", "New age, wow" ))

I want to replace only "New age, wow" with "Yes" without affecting the first string. That is,
df_2<-data.frame(SS=c("New age, wow 20", "Yes" ))

I tried, as usual, using str_replace but it did not work.
str_replace(df$SS, "New age, wow", "Yes")

Note that my real vector contains thousands of such similar cases, so the order of the strings here is normally random

What about
stringr::str_replace(df$SS, "^New age, wow$", "Yes")
# [1] "New age, wow 20" "Yes"


Thank you. If I want to have a vector of multiple replacements, rather than one that I have in my example, how can the above code can be modified?

@newfinder Multiple replacements for the same "New age, wow" or for multiple strings?

I checked and the code you provided above seems to do multiple replacements for the same "New age, wow". So we should be OK in that regard. Or not?  Regarding my question here, I mean multiple replacements for multiple strings, for example, we could also have "Las vega, 2010" and "Las vega". Thank you a lot

Using startsWith.
> df
               SS
1 New age, wow 20
2    New age, wow
3    New age, wow
4             Foo

> transform(df, SS=replace(SS, c(FALSE, sapply(SS[-1], startsWith, x=SS[1])), 'Yes'))
               SS
1 New age, wow 20
2             Yes
3             Yes
4             Foo


Data:
> dput(df)
structure(list(SS = c("New age, wow 20", "New age, wow", "New age, wow", 
"Foo")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))


Thank you. The problem is that my vector, as I mentioned above contains thousands of such various  characters, where I can not locate their index position in advance

@newfinder You probably mean strings rather than characters. You may want to make a more realistic example. I already added non-related string "Foo" to the variable.

What about this?
> transform(df, SS = replace(SS, SS == "New age, wow", "Yes"))
               SS
1 New age, wow 20
2             Yes


Thank you. If I want to have a vector of multiple replacements, rather than one that I have in my example, how can the above code can be modified?
